# Error connecting to AuthorizeNet only on live server

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Currently we are using Authorize.net as payment gateway for our existing project. In Authorize.net we are using php sdk. In staging server sandbox mode is working perfectly but live server we are getting error message as (Error connecting to AuthorizeNet)- screenshot below. Where I am doing wrong, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your posting URL, your transaction ID & loginID.
2. Update your SDK library. Check for the cert.pem file in that. If outdated it will generate error.
3. You can disable ssl verify peer to avoid this error by 
   $trans->VERIFY_PEER = false